# React Native: Call a function outside PanResponder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a PanResponder like suggested in the React Native docs.

I interpolate the pan value to a rotation value, which then rotates a view.

onPanResponderRelease i want to call a function that triggers an animation.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [pan, setPan] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const rotation = pan.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-100, 0, 100],
    outputRange: ["-360deg", "0deg", "360deg"],
  }); 

  const animateRotation = () => {
    Animated.timing(pan, {
      toValue: pan._value + 100,
      duration: 3000,
      useNativeDriver: false,
      easing: Easing.ease,
    }).start();
  };

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
        // what is happening!
        // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}
        // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
        // gestureState.d{x,y}
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The user has released all touches while this view is the
        // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
      animateRotation();
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
        // should be cancelled
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
        // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.
        return true;
      },
    }),
  ).current;

  return <View {...panResponder.panHandlers} style={{transform: [{rotate: rotation}]}}/>;
};
```

The function gets called, however, the animation does not happen or is not visible.

Now if i add a state

```
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
```

and set the state inside the onPanResponderRelease function and wrap the animateRotation function inside an useEffect, everything works perfectly fine.

```
  onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
     // The user has released all touches while this view is the
     // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
     setAnimation(true);
  },

  useEffect(() => {
    if (animate) {
      setTest(animate);
      Animated.timing(pan, {
        toValue: pan._value + 100,
        duration: 3000,
        useNativeDriver: false,
        easing: Easing.ease,
      }).start();
    }
  }, [animate]);
```

Why is this and how can I call the animateRotation function without the workaround with useState and useEffect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a pan responder to activate the animation when `onPanResponderRelease`? 
Does `<Pressable onPressOut={animateRotation} />` not work?

Answer (score 0):

The `React.useRef` of the pan responder saves the state value.
Try to remove or replace with a `React.useMemo`.
Be careful because the `gestureState` values may not work as expected, as the useRef store these values

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/tinder-like-swipe)

1. Create refs in the parent component
2. Pass the refs to the tinder SwipeableCard
3. Utilize useImperativeHandle to call animation functions

App.js

```js
// React Native Swipeable Card View UI like Tinder
// https://aboutreact.com/react-native-swipeable-cardview-like-tinder/

// import React in our code
import React, { useState, useRef, useMemo } from 'react';

// import all the components we are going to use
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Pressable,
} from 'react-native';
import { SwipeableCard } from './components/SwipeableCard';

const alreadyRemoved = [];

const App = () => {
  const [noMoreCard, setNoMoreCard] = useState(false);
  const [sampleCardArray, setSampleCardArray] = useState(DEMO_CONTENT);
  const [swipeDirection, setSwipeDirection] = useState('--');
  const swipeAnim = useRef();

  const removeCard = (id) => {
    // alert(id);
    sampleCardArray.splice(
      sampleCardArray.findIndex((item) => item.id == id),
      1
    );
    setSampleCardArray(sampleCardArray);
    if (sampleCardArray.length == 0) {
      setNoMoreCard(true);
    }
  };

  const childRefs = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(DEMO_CONTENT.length)
        .fill(0)
        .map((i) => React.createRef()),
    []
  );

  const lastSwipedDirection = (swipeDirection) => {
    setSwipeDirection(swipeDirection);
  };

  const swipe = (dir) => {
    const cardsLeft = sampleCardArray.filter(
      (card) => !alreadyRemoved.includes(card.cardTitle)
    );
    if (cardsLeft.length) {
      const toBeRemoved = cardsLeft[cardsLeft.length - 1].cardTitle; // Find the card object to be removed
      const index = DEMO_CONTENT.map((card) => card.cardTitle).indexOf(
        toBeRemoved
      ); // Find the index of which to make the reference to
      alreadyRemoved.push(toBeRemoved); // Make sure the next card gets removed next time if this card do not have time to exit the screen

      if (dir === 'right') {
        childRefs[index].current.sRight(); // Swipe the card!
      }
      if (dir === 'left') {
        childRefs[index].current.sLeft(); // Swipe the card!
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>
        React Native Swipeable Card View UI like Tinder
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.swipeText}>
        Last Card Swipe Direction was{'\n'}
        {swipeDirection}
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {sampleCardArray.map((item, key) => (
          <SwipeableCard
            ref={childRefs[key]}
            key={key}
            item={item}
            removeCard={() => removeCard(item.id)}
            swipedDirection={lastSwipedDirection}
            swipeAnim={swipeAnim}
          />
        ))}
        {noMoreCard ? (
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, color: '#000' }}>No Cards Found.</Text>
        ) : null}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.dotContainer}>
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            swipe('left');
          }}
          style={styles.dot}>
          <Text>Left</Text>
        </Pressable>
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            swipe('right');
          }}
          style={styles.dot}>
          <Text>Right</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  dotContainer: { flexDirection: 'row' },
  dot: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  swipeText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

const DEMO_CONTENT = [
  {
    id: '1',
    cardTitle: 'Card 1',
    backgroundColor: '#FFC107',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    cardTitle: 'Card 2',
    backgroundColor: '#ED2525',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    cardTitle: 'Card 3',
    backgroundColor: '#E7088E',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    cardTitle: 'Card 4',
    backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    cardTitle: 'Card 5',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFB14',
  },
].reverse();
```

SwipeableCard:

```js
// React Native Swipeable Card View UI like Tinder
// https://aboutreact.com/react-native-swipeable-cardview-like-tinder/

// import React in our code
import React, {
  useState,
  useRef,
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
} from 'react';

// import all the components we are going to use
import {
  Text,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const SwipeableCard = forwardRef(function (
  { item, removeCard, swipedDirection, swipeAnim },
  ref
) {
  // let xPosition = new Animated.Value(0);
  const [xPosition, setXPosition] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const swipeView = useRef();
  let swipeDirection = '';
  let cardOpacity = new Animated.Value(1);
  let rotateCard = xPosition.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
    outputRange: ['-20deg', '0deg', '20deg'],
  });

  const swipeRight = () => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(xPosition, {
        toValue: SCREEN_WIDTH,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
      Animated.timing(cardOpacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
    ]).start(() => {
      removeCard();
    });
  };

  const swipeLeft = () => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(xPosition, {
        toValue: -SCREEN_WIDTH,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
      Animated.timing(cardOpacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
    ]).start(() => {
      removeCard();
    });
  };

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        sLeft() {
          swipeLeft();
        },
        sRight() {
          swipeRight();
        },
      };
    },
    []
  );

  let panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
      xPosition.setValue(gestureState.dx);
      if (gestureState.dx > SCREEN_WIDTH - 250) {
        swipeDirection = 'Right';
      } else if (gestureState.dx < -SCREEN_WIDTH + 250) {
        swipeDirection = 'Left';
      }
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
      if (
        gestureState.dx < SCREEN_WIDTH - 150 &&
        gestureState.dx > -SCREEN_WIDTH + 150
      ) {
        swipedDirection('--');
        Animated.spring(xPosition, {
          toValue: 0,
          speed: 5,
          bounciness: 10,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      } else if (gestureState.dx > SCREEN_WIDTH - 150) {
        swipeRight();
      } else if (gestureState.dx < -SCREEN_WIDTH + 150) {
        swipeRight();
      }
    },
  });

  swipeAnim.current = panResponder.panHandlers;

  return (
    <Animated.View
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      ref={swipeView}
      style={[
        styles.cardStyle,
        {
          backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor,
          opacity: cardOpacity,
          transform: [{ translateX: xPosition }, { rotate: rotateCard }],
        },
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.cardTitleStyle}> {item.cardTitle} </Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardStyle: {
    width: '75%',
    height: '45%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    borderRadius: 7,
  },
  cardTitleStyle: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  swipeText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export { SwipeableCard };
```